# Why does frozen then cooked fish smell more and what is this smell?

Tags: fish, smell

I have noticed that if I quickly simmer whitebait(and sometimes other fish which was frozen at sea) in water the fish/water quickly becomes smelly.

I doubt it's overcooking smell because the smell **starts to appear as the whitebait heats and is not there when frozen**.  To be fair I am a sensitive individual so will notice more smell/taste then others but the question remains, if not from overcooking, what is this chemical?

If whitebait is frozen at sea, if cooked from forzen 2 months later it should not smell of anything right since it was frozen, or do trimethylines or some other chemical still increase while frozen? Please explain and if not trimethyline please explain what other chemical might be.

It could be that I'm overcooking as Ive noticed the same smell when cooking other fish however i am cooking within a few minutes and like I say the smell appears as the fish heats so perhaps is not from overcooking.  Again I notice it occur with frozen fish making me think something is building up over time and subsequent cooking\chemical reaction activates a new smell.